# How do I replace current alert() in javascript to be jQuery Alert Dialogs plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Currently I'm using simple javascript alert box to validate my input. Now I want to change it to be **[jQuery Alert Dialogs](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/alerts/demo/)**

I'm trying something like this, but doesn't work.

Javascript:

```
function validation() {
    str = document.step;
    if (str.full_name.value == "") {
    jAlert('Please enter this field', 'Alert Dialog');
    //alert('Please enter this field');
        str.full_name.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="step" name="step" onsubmit="return validation();">
<input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Let me know

Comment: When you say, "it doesn't worked", what exactly do you mean?  What **does** happen; an error? Nothing?  Something that's like what you want but not quite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using jQuery, so there's no reason to not write [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

#### HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" id="step">
    <input id="full_name" name="full_name" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function ()
{
    var $fullName = $('#full_name');

    $('#step').submit(function ()
    {
        if (!$fullName.val())
        {
            jAlert('Please enter this field', 'Alert Dialog');
            $fullName.focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/ZQ82V/)***

Make sure that your page includes all of the dependencies:

- [jQuery JS](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.js)
- [jQuery UI draggable JS](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/alerts/demo/jquery.ui.draggable.js)
- [jAlert JS](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/alerts/demo/jquery.alerts.js) and [CSS](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/alerts/demo/jquery.alerts.css)